# Glitch in Safari when using backdrop filters

Tags: css

I'm experiencing a strange collection of glitches when using backdrop filters on a pseudo element. I'm using the blur and saturate filters.

I know that this is relatively new CSS and is only supported by Safari as far as I've read, but I'm wondering if anyone has had similar problems and if there's a workaround for this?

I have a hover menu on my website in which the submenu has a little arrow at the top. I've made this using `border-left`, `border-right` and `border-bottom`. I've tried to apply the same backdrop filters to the pseudo element arrow that I've applied to the submenu itself, but this is resulting in glitchy colours appearing every time I hover over the main menu link. Sometimes they work okay, but depending on their positioning over the background image, this problem does consistently occur at various viewport widths.

https://jsfiddle.net/fm1cg4n4/4/

```
<header class="header">

  <nav class="menu">

    <ul>

      <li>Menu Link 1
        <ul>
          <li>Submenu Link 1</li>
          <li>Submenu Link 2</li>
          <li>Submenu Link 3</li>
          <li>Submenu Link 4</li>
          <li>Submenu Link 5</li>
        </ul>
      </li>

    </ul>

  </nav>

</header>

body {
  background-image: url(http://www.lucieaverillphotography.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/15974858_10154941714967990_2444361563480701659_o.jpg);
  background-size:cover;
}

.header {
  position:absolute;
  height:55px;
  width:100%;
}

nav ul {
  display:flex;
  height:55px;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

nav ul li {
  padding:10px;
  list-style:none;
  color:#fff;
}

nav ul ul {
  position:absolute;
  top:100%;
  left:10px;
  z-index:10;
  display:block;
  min-width:185px;
  height:auto;
  padding: 2px 0px;
  background-color:#ffffff;
  opacity:0;
  pointer-events:none;

  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(7px) saturate(200%);
    backdrop-filter: blur(7px) saturate(200%);
  border-style:none;

  transition: opacity 0.5s ease 0s;
}

nav ul li:hover ul {
  pointer-events:auto;
  opacity:1;
}

nav ul ul:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 26px;
  margin-top: -2px;

  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(7px) saturate(200%);
  backdrop-filter: blur(7px) saturate(200%);
}

nav ul ul li {
  color:#444;
}
```

Comment: which version of safari are you using?

Comment: I'm using  version 10.0.2, my Mac has been bugging me for updates for a while now so maybe that's it.

Answer (score -1):

In pseudo 'nav ul ul:before' remove filters. Update your css to the following:

```
nav ul ul:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 26px;
  margin-top: -2px;

  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
```

Remove:

<strike>-webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(7px) saturate(200%);</strike>

<strike>backdrop-filter: blur(7px) saturate(200%);</strike>

Check https://jsfiddle.net/codeMonk/fm1cg4n4/5/ in safari.

[image]

This should do the job.

Comment: Hi, yes I know it's the filters causing the glitch, so removing them will obviously stop it happening, but I added them for a reason I want to use them on the pseudo element otherwise it doesn't match with the submenu.